# Swipe or ScrollTo or TouchAction not working in iOS Simulator with Appium 1.4.13, Xcode 7.0.1, IOS 8.x/9.0 and Java-Client 3.2.0

Tags: ios, scroll, appium, simulator

Swipe or ScrollTo or TouchAction not working in iOS Simulator with Appium 1.4.13, Xcode 7.0.1, iOS 8.x/9.0 and Java-Client 3.2.0

Any working solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this scrollTo method:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) iosDriver; 
HashMap <String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap <String, String>();
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement)iosDriver.findElement(By.name("elementName"))).getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```